# How can I add data to core data using one-to-many relationship?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am wanting to add a day to a week record. I have setup the entities and the relationship within xcode however am unsure on the next step.

Am I right in thinking that I need to manually set the automatically generated foreign key field?

**Currently my save code for dat is as follow:**

```
    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext{
        day = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Days", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Days
        day.day = text!
        day.restDay = restday

        do{
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            print("saved a day to SQLite")
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
```

**Model(s)**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you auto-generated code for this model (by letting XCode create subclasses of NSManagedObject), then you're all set. All you need to do it have an instance of `Weeks` available (say, as a parameter to the function) when creating your `Days` instance, and add this line before saving the context:

```
day.dayWeek = week // assuming 'week' is an existing instance of Weeks
```

This will add the `Weeks` instance to your `Days` instance, and automatically add your `Days` instance to the (un)ordered set of `Days` in that same `Weeks` instance.